# C++ compile problem with strlen and strcpy

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[5],b[5];
    cout<<strlen(a)<<endl;
    strcpy(a,b);
}
```

when I compile the code using `g++ filename.cpp` the code will be compiled with no issues but when my friends try to do it using dev-c++, they'll get errors!

based on [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/?kw=strcpy), I am the one who should get errors!!

so I am just wondering what's causing the difference here?

P.S: I have tried different versions of C++ using `-std=c++98` throw `-std=c++2a`

Comment: Try using g++ -o test filename.cpp

Comment: You have UB in your code, what do you expect from it?

Comment: #include <cstring>

Comment: You haven't initialized `a` so the results are unpredictable. This can account for random behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strlen` and `strcpy` are declared in the `<cstring>` header.  Some standard library implementations might include that in `<iostream>`, some might not.  This explains why it may compile with some setups and not others.

Answer (score 3):

```
char a[5],b[5];
cout<<strlen(a)<<endl;
strcpy(a,b);
```

Both `a` and `b` are uninitialised. Your program has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The compiler has no obligation to generate anything in particular. *Any* behaviour is acceptable. You cannot reason about code with UB. The program is simply invalid/broken (and the compiler is also not obligated to warn you about UB btw).

As for failing to compile: you did not include the header defining `strcpy` and `strlen`. That's in `<cstring>`. Include that header and the code should compile (it'll still be broken, but it should *compile*)..

Standard library headers (like `iostream`) are *allowed* to include other headers, but they are not *required* to do so. So, on some systems you may be able to get away with not including a header since some other one pulls it in for you. But that's not guaranteed and you shouldn't rely on it. *Always* explicitly include the headers for the stuff you need/use.

Comment: the problem is not the behavior of the program, the problem is the behavior of C++ compiler on different systems